# mobile atlas creator for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkmapview

I am trying to use this application [here](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to create offline map tiles and data that would be used with mapkit.

I think it might be a long stretch but I have looked everywhere trying to get this offline map action working but I cannot catch a break.

any tips of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mapkit only works with Google Maps. You cannot choose another tiles provider than GMaps. Therefore you are wasting your time if you keep that goal.  This blog article (OSM and RouteMe) is more like what you are trying to achieve: http://shikii.net/blog/offline-maps-in-ios-using-openstreetmap-and-route-me/

Comment: you can create georefrenced images that are used in mapkit as another layer, this I know works because I have done it perfectly with a png georefrenced image before. The issue now that I am having is I cannot find a decent quality image that is georefrenced of the area i would like to have offline maps for.\

Comment: Well unfortunately that is not development related. SO is not Yahoo Answers ;-). You shouldn't find much help here.

Comment: Yes, this should be moved to a more appropriate stack like http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can now cache maps for offline use in Google Maps 2.0 for iOS. See https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567?hl=en&rd=1

If you really want to use Mobile Atlas Creator (MOBAC) you can create a map or "atlas", transfer it to iOS, then import into [Galileo](http://galileo-app.com/). The map import feature is a 7 day free trial in Galileo.

See the "Using MOBAC" tab up top at http://mobac.sourceforge.net/quickstart/ and http://galileo-app.com/manual.html#offline_maps

Depending on what kind of map you are looking for you maybe able to find an app specifically for your purposes so you can skip MOBAC. For example for offline topographic maps there's http://topomapsapp.com/ that uses USGS 24k.